# MongoDB shell syntax error issue

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Given this document:

```
{
  "_id": 0,
  "name": "Usman Shehu",
  "dp": "ol.jpg",
  "contacts": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "Ahmad Sani",
      "dp": "ol.jpg",
      "m": "Messages:12",
      "time": "01:27am",
      "chats": [
        {
          "msg": "hello there",
          "t": "12:45am",
          "des": "from"
        },
        {
          "msg": "how far...",
          "t": "12:47am",
          "des": "to"
        },
        {
          "msg": "so far so good",
          "t": "01:05pm",
          "des": "from"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If i try to run this query ...

```
db.gist.update({"contacts.id":0},{$push:{chats:{"msg":"Test4","des":"from","t":"06:38pm"}}})
```

... it is not updating the "chats" array but adding it as new field in the within the document.

Please any help?

Comment: The chats might be an array but the path to chats is not specified so use $push:{contacts.$.chats:{//updating values}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
db.gist.update({"contacts.id":0},{$push:{"contacts.$.chats":{"msg":"Test4","des":"from","t":"06:38pm"}}})
```

You have to specify `contacts.$.chat` for the `$push` command, because `contacts.chat` is a nested array you have to use the [positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/).

Running the above command against the document supplied in your question produces the following, updated, document:

```
{
    "_id" : 0,
    "name" : "Usman Shehu",
    "dp" : "ol.jpg",
    "contacts" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 0,
            "name" : "Ahmad Sani",
            "dp" : "ol.jpg",
            "m" : "Messages:12",
            "time" : "01:27am",
            "chats" : [ 
                {
                    "msg" : "hello there",
                    "t" : "12:45am",
                    "des" : "from"
                }, 
                {
                    "msg" : "how far...",
                    "t" : "12:47am",
                    "des" : "to"
                }, 
                {
                    "msg" : "so far so good",
                    "t" : "01:05pm",
                    "des" : "from"
                }, 
                {
                    "msg" : "Test4",
                    "des" : "from",
                    "t" : "06:38pm"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Note: the docs state that:

> the positional $ operator acts as a placeholder for the first match of the update query document.

Your update query document (`{"contacts.id":0}`) uses an `id` which *suggests* that there is only one expected match so using the positional operator should be ok for your use case. However, it's worth noting that if the update query document matches multiple contacts then only the first matched contact will be updated.

Comment: It works!, thanks alot glytching, this is my first question on stackoverflow and you are my first attendant. am motivated and inspired.